# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'nameofColumn' datatable

Tags: python, datatable, flask-restful

I have a large file that contains a table. I am going to open it with the `datatable` package in python. Consider the following code

```
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f
df = dt.open('Mybigfile.nff')
df = df[(f.c1 > 0) & (f.c1 < 100),:]
print(df.shape)
```

when I run it like `python code.py` where `code.py` contains the above code, everything is fine.

But when I put the code in an flask-api  I get the error

`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'c1'`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from json import dumps
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app) 

class test(Resource):
    def get(self):
        df = dt.open('Mybigfile.nff')
        df = df[(f.c1 > 0) & (f.c1 < 100),:]
        print(df.shape)
        return 1

api.add_resource(test, '/gettest')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',port=12345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error comes from expression `(f.c1 > 0)`. For some reason (and I don't know how it happens), your `f` variable is not the object imported from `datatable`, but rather an object of class `_io.TextIOWrapper`.

The problem can be resolved, however, with one of these workarounds:

1. Import `f` under a different name, for example `from datatable import f as F`. Then you'll write `df[(F.c1 > 0) & (F.c1 < 100), :]`.
2. Use `f` directly from the `dt` namespace: `df[(dt.f.c1 > 0) & (dt.f.c1 < 100), :]`.

Finally, you can try to find out how `f` became a TextIOWrapper in the first place. You probably have a code fragment somewhere that reads `with open(...) as f: ...`. When that piece is executed, `f` becomes redefined.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I ran into this because of `f = open(config_dir + os.sep + 'api_key.txt', 'r')` a hundred lines higher in the same script where I was also using datatable `f` expressions. DOH!